# Как вписать один SKShapeNode в границы другого SKShapeNode?

Tags: swift, spritekit

Есть 2 `SKShapeNode`. 1 больше другого по размерам. Нужно вписать меньший по размеру в границы большего и передать ему координаты большего (что-бы позиция второго нода уже определялась координатами не сцены, а именно первого большого нода).

Comment: можно больше деталей? маленький нод child большого? или frame маленького должен быть рассчитан таким образом, чтобы он визуально был внутри большого?

Comment: маленький нод child большого. координаты передавать не обязательно. мне главное понять, как не выпустить маленький нод за границы большого без добавления дополнительных нодов - борьеров